# Is it considered bad practice/design to create 10s/100s of Guice Injectors?

Tags: java, design-patterns, guice

**Consider a hypothetical application:**

- That has a need to create tens or even hundreds of small groups of objects

  - (Group A: Class A instance, Class D instance, Class M instance. Properties P')
  - (Group B: Class B instance, Class D instance)
  - (Group C: Class B instance, Class D instance, Class F instance. Properties P'')
- Each of these objects are created by its own Provider that is registered with the parent/root Injector using MapBinder or MultiBinder (typical "plugin" usecase)
- To create each group, a new child Injector is created that uses the Providers from the root and a few other providers that are local to this child Injector - like configuration/properties bindings
- This tight group of objects is created together to perform some task and then discarded together - after a few hours
- The group has some unique parameters

  - Meaning, that each object created within the group has distinct configuration properties
  - They are different from another instance of that class in a different group

**Question:**
Assuming that for some reason the problem described above cannot be accomplished by using run of the mill design patterns like Factory, Builder, Creator etc:

- Is there anything wrong with the approach described above?

  - Performance, memory foot print
  - Readability (vs using plain old Java `new`)
- Does it sound too complicated and relying on libraries to do something simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the level of abstraction you described, that sounds like a reasonable solution, and conducive to some good design patterns (like loose coupling and instance immutability). To the best of my knowledge Guice will not pose any greater threat of memory leaks or other performance problems than any comparable solution for those complex needs—just keep an eye on which references you keep so the GC can do its job.

To that point you may want to be careful about creating singleton objects in Guice, though, if you rely on them being garbage collected. Objects declared as `@Singleton` (or `asEagerSingleton` or `toInstance`) cannot be garbage-collected as long as the Injector is reachable, because the Injector is obligated to return the exact same instance if it is ever asked for again. In desktop VMs it may be cheaper to get multiple instances of a stateless object so the GC can collect them all, rather than declaring the object as a singleton that can never be collected.

Comment: You rightfully pointed out "..for those complex needs". It could've been accomplished using Design Patterns, but that is moot. So, there are no other gotchas regarding creating multiple child injectors concurrently across threads?

Comment: There shouldn't be thread issues there. Note that [singleton creation happens within a global lock](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/issues/detail?id=183), which does mean that you shouldn't spawn threads within class initializers, constructors, or injected setters, but that makes enough sense anyway. Let non-@Inject methods do your heavy lifting.